# Se salta la solicitud de valores

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un mapa de caracteres y uno de los problemas que tengo es que al pedir los valores, se salta uno en medio. Es decir, me pide el dato 1 y luego el 3. Muestra por pantalla que introduzca el valor 2, pero no deja, ya que directamente se pasa al 3.
Otro de los problemas que tengo es que no muestra por pantalla los valores. Lo que me piden es lo siguiente. Me dan una serie de caracteres que están almacenados en un array (Son los que aparecen en el código como vletras). Después el usuario tiene que introducir caracteres hasta llenar una matriz de 3x4. Y el programa tiene que comprobar si el carácter introducido está en el array. Si es así, debe escribir en una matriz de punteros la dirección del carácter introducido en vletras. Y lo debe introducir en la misma posición en que se ha introducido el valor. Si no se encuentra el carácter debe introducirse NULL. Al final pide mostrar la matriz de punteros con el valor al que apunta y si es NULL, mostrar asterisco.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXF 3
#define MAXC 4
#define VALOR 10

int main (void)
{
char vletras[]={'A','F','H','K','L','O','S','U','X','Z'};
int i,j,k;
char tabla[MAXF][MAXC];
char *mapa[MAXF][MAXC];

for (i=0;i<MAXF;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<MAXC;j++)
    {
        printf ("\nIntroduzca valor [%d][%d]: ",i+1,j+1);
        scanf ("%c",&tabla[i][j]);
        for (k=0;k<VALOR;k++)
        {
            if (tabla[i][j]==vletras[k])
            {
                mapa[i][j]=vletras[k];
            }
            else
            {
                mapa[i][j]=NULL;
            }
        }
    }
}

for (i=0;i<MAXF;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<MAXC;j++)
        {
            if(mapa[i][j]==NULL)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            else
            {
                printf ("%c",*mapa[i][j]);
            }    
        }
    }

printf("\n");
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Ingresas un caracter, luego le das enter. Lee el caracter, y en la segunda
pasada lee el salto de linea que le colocaste, por eso es que te sale el error.
La solucion es simple, luego de leer el caracter ignora el siguiete (que sera el
`\n`). Tu lectura tendria que ser: `scanf ("%c%*c",&tabla[i][j]);` El `*` le dice que lo lea,  pero que no lo vas a guardar en ninguna variable.

Comment: Para que no te pille el caracter del salto de línea, introduce un espacio antes del `%c`. Déjalo del siguiente modo: `scanf (" %c",&tabla[i][j]);`

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas. Funcionan las 2.